# RxJava not running on Background thread

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android, android-room

I am trying to save data in Room and it requires some background thread to save data. So I have created an observable like this

```
val obs: Observable<MutableLiveData<List<Source>>>? = Observable.fromCallable(object :Callable<MutableLiveData<List<Source>>>{
            override fun call(): MutableLiveData<List<Source>> {

                return mutableLiveData
            }
        })
```

Then I am subscribing, observing and unsubscribing it like this

```
obs?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())?.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                ?.subscribe(object : Observer<MutableLiveData<List<Source>>>{
                    override fun onComplete() {

                    }

                    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable?) {

                    }

                    override fun onNext(value: MutableLiveData<List<Source>>?) {
                        for(source in value!!.value!!.iterator()){
                            sourceDao.insert(source)//this is the line number 87, that logcat is pointing
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                        e?.printStackTrace()
                    }
                })
```

I am subscribing it on the Schedulers.io thread then observing it on the AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() but still I am getting not on background thread error. More specifically

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:204)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:251)
06-18 11:11:08.674 3732-3732/com.theanilpaudel.technewspro W/System.err:     at com.package.myapp.room.SourceDao_Impl.insert(SourceDao_Impl.java:63)
        at com.package.myapp.main.MainRepository$saveToRoom$1.onNext(MainRepository.kt:87)
        at com.package.myapp.main.MainRepository$saveToRoom$1.onNext(MainRepository.kt:76)
```

Comment: `onNext` is executed on MainThread due to your `observeOn` Operation.

Comment: what other threads we have?

Answer (score 2):

Execute your DB operation within the Observable and not in your Observer:

```
val obs: Observable<MutableLiveData<List<Source>>>? = Observable.fromCallable(object :Callable<MutableLiveData<List<Source>>>{
        override fun call(): MutableLiveData<List<Source>> {
             for(source in mutableLiveData!!.value!!.iterator()){
                  sourceDao.insert(source)
             }
            return mutableLiveData
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())?.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            ?.subscribe(object : Observer<MutableLiveData<List<Source>>>{
                override fun onComplete() {

                }

                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable?) {

                }

                override fun onNext(value: MutableLiveData<List<Source>>?) {
                    // Nothing todo right more
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                    e?.printStackTrace()
                }
            })
    })
```

Comment: I tried this and it isn't working. Isn't it the same thing though

Comment: No, because the inserts are executed in the Observable not in the Observer. Is not working is no valid error description.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense because you have `observeOn` the main thread and you are doing your work in the observer (`observeOn` manages the thread of the observer).

To fix this, you can use flatmap on your `obs` and do the for loop in there. Since flatmap requires you to return an Observable, you can `return Observable.just(true)` after your for loop.